# How to edit the existing java source file by using the plugin development API in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin. I need to access the java files in the project and have to edit them. As of now I can able to get the source of the jave file using the API org.eclipse.jdt.core.ISourceReference. How can I edit the source.

Kindly give me some ideas,
Thanks in advance,

Easwar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Eclipse Help for a simple example http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm